# Source that martyrs don't feel pain?

Tags: sources-mekorot, death, martyr

A lot of people have told me (and I seem to remember seeing so myself) there is a view in the Rishonim that someone who is killed Al Kiddush Hashem (for the sanctification of G-d's name, ie., martyrdom) does not feel the pain. [In this thread](http://www.needaneitzah.com/questions/27/is-it-true-that-those-killed-al-kiddush-hashem-dont-feel-the-pain) people have pointed out a few proofs that they definitely did feel the pain.

What is the source that there is no pain when being killed for Hashem?

Comment: Related: [How to reconcile these two different statements on dying Al Kiddush Hashem](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17657/1145)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Per http://www.ashlag.com/parasha_in.asp?id=206&idd=5 this is based on a Maharam M'Rotenberg. The pain is not felt if the person is not anticipating a miracle, however if the person is anticipating a miracle then he does feel the pain.

> בשו״ת מהר״ם מרוטנבערג (סימן תקט״ז) דכשגמר האדם בדעתו למות על קידוש השם
>   ומסר נפשו על זה, אז מכאן ואילך כל מה שעושים לו אינו מרגיש, ולכן מובן
>   מה שמצינו שכשהקדושים הושלכו באש לא צעקו כלל, אף שהאדם הנוגע באצבעו באש
>   אי אפשר שלא יצעק, כי כשהולך על קידוש השם שאני. אך במה דברים אמורים
>   כשמוסר נפשו למות, אבל אם מצפה לנס ולא גמר בדעתו למות, אז מרגיש את
>   היסורים.‏

The Teshuva says `סימן תקט״ז`, but it [actually is סימן תקי״ז](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=11624&st=&pgnum=104).

Comment: Amazing, just what I was looking for! Makes the Kasha even stronger when the opinon is sourced!

Comment: This answer answers both questions.

Comment: How does it answer the Amoiroim?

Comment: They were awaiting a miracle.

Comment: Reb Yishmoel defitily wasnt. He had already gone to Shomayim and they had told him it was a decree from Heaven!

Comment: Just because it was a decree does not mean they were not awaiting a miracle. Perhaps by allowing this to happen it would be counted as if it happened, similar to Akeidas Yitzchok. Perhaps they even wanted the pain to atone for the sins of Klal Yisroel.

Comment: Do you have access to the rest of the teshuva? I checked the source that you quoted this from, and it's all they have. Clearly (since it begins with דכשגמר), this is following on from another observation that the Maharam made. Perhaps the entire thing would make this clearer? (+1 BTW: this was very well spotted).

Comment: I can't seem to find that Shu"t. Can someone locate it? Perhaps mine has a different numbering scheme?

Comment: This is the only Teshuva of his numbered 516 that I could find http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1137&st=&pgnum=212&hilite=

Comment: @DoubleAA, [Found it](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=11624&st=&pgnum=104). (It's actually 517.)

Comment: @jake Thanks! I had searched for דכשגמר אדם but I didn't account for the authors added prefixes.

Comment: Outstanding! Though I evidently need glasses :) I'm going to try not to spend TOO much time on this, but will probably spend too much time on this...

Comment: Is anybody else bothered by the fact that the quote above is not what the printed passage says?

Comment: @ShimonbM Yes it certainly is different. But it is close enough that I'm guessing there is a different edition of Maharam's responsa that might have it that way. The hunt resumes...

Comment: The Hebrew is from Ashlag.com which is inferring that from the Maharam M'Rotenberg. I thought that was clear.

Comment: @DoubleAA, More likely they're doing some selective quoting.

Comment: @GershonGold If that text has their interpretation in it, do you mind if I paste in the entire original text in its stead?

Comment: I do not mind. This answer was given originally to 2 questions which has now been divided, and that part is not necessary anymore.

Comment: Oy I forgot to paste in the original. I'll do that tonight bli shevu'a

Comment: @DoubleAA looking forward eagerly

Answer (score 2):

For a comprehensive review of this topic and a broad list of sources see Michael Fishbane's "The Kiss of God" chapter 2: [The Sanctification of God in Love](http://books.google.com/books?id=CG03ih1LHg8C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false). Among the sources he cites is the Shu"T MaHaram quoted above but he quotes the later Rabbi Moshe Galante's Koheles Yaakov (73a) as sourcing this idea in Tosfos; he writes:

> In my opinion, the sense [of this verse (Koheles 8:5)] is similar to what is adduced by the Tosafists... following a tradition of sages [of France]: 'Those who are burnt and killed for the sanctification of His Name do not experience this torment but die [painlessly] by the [divine] kiss.'

He cites many other sources for this idea as well.

Comment: Maharam was a Tosafist so those are essentially the same source.

Comment: @DoubleAA Though he may have been a contemporary, the reference was to the baalei tosfos of France which procludes Rabbi Meir of Rothenburg.

Comment: user1668 Rabbi Meïr ben Solomon of Perpignan, referred to Rab Meir of Rothenberg, as the "greatest Jewish leader of Zarfat" alive at the time, Zarfat is medieval Hebrew for France which was a reference to Charlemagne's rule of Germany. from https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meir_of_Rothenburg